# Experiencing Memory Exhaustion Issue with Select Field in Repeater

Tags: laravel, filamentphp

Hey I am running into an issue where memory is exhausted.

I'm facing a memory exhaustion problem in my Filamentphp (v3) application. The issue seems to be related to a Select field within a repeater, specifically within an `OrderResource`. The field is responsible for retrieving around 20k records for selection or searching.

```
Select::make('product_id')
    ->hidden(function () use ($productId) {
        return $productId !== null;
    })
    ->options(function (Get $get) {
        $supplierId = $get('../../supplier_id');
        if ($supplierId) {
            return Product::select('id', DB::raw("CONCAT(item_code, ' - ', item_description) as concatenated_value"))
                ->where('supplier_id', $supplierId)
                ->where('available', true)
                ->pluck('concatenated_value', 'id')
                ->toArray();
        }

        return ['Selecteer eerst een merk'];
    })
    ->label('Product')
    ->searchable()
    ->preload()
    ->disabled(fn(Get $get) => $get('../../sent'))
    ->columnSpan(2)
    ->required();
```

When I comment out the entire field, the application runs smoothly. However, having this field active causes a memory exhaustion error due to the large dataset.

Any suggestions on how to optimize the performance of this Select field, especially considering it's used within a repeater in an `OrderResource`? The `OrderResource` allows users to view orders and provides the option to select products from the chosen

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to limit the number of records retrieved (it doesn't seem like a problem to me since the field is searchable). You can achieve this in a few ways:

The first method involves using `->optionsLimit()`:

```
Select::make('product_id')
    ->hidden(function () use ($productId) {
        return $productId !== null;
    })
    ->options(function (Get $get) {
        $supplierId = $get('../../supplier_id');
        if ($supplierId) {
            return Product::select('id', DB::raw("CONCAT(item_code, ' - ', item_description) as concatenated_value"))
                ->where('supplier_id', $supplierId)
                ->where('available', true)
                ->pluck('concatenated_value', 'id')
                ->toArray();
        }

        return ['Selecteer eerst een merk'];
    })
    ->label('Product')
    ->searchable()
    ->preload()
    ->disabled(fn(Get $get) => $get('../../sent'))
    ->columnSpan(2)
    ->optionsLimit(20)
    ->required();
```

The second one is use a `limit` in the query. To do that and simplify your code, use [getSearchResultsUsing](https://docs.laravel-filament.cn/docs/forms/fields/select/#returning-custom-search-results)*****:

```
Select::make('product_id')
                ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn (string $search): array => 
                       Product::select('id', DB::raw("CONCAT(item_code, ' - ', item_description) as concatenated_value"))
                       ->where('supplier_id', $supplierId)
                       ->where('available', true)
                       ->limit(20)->pluck('name', 'id')
                       ->toArray()
                )
```

If these methods aren't sufficient, I recommend loading the select without records. Only search and show records after the user types 3 or 4 characters (while also limiting the retrieved records).

You can also use a [debounce](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/advanced#debouncing-reactive-fields) to make the page smoother. This means the component will wait a few seconds after the user stops typing in the search input before sending the request to the backend. With fewer requests, there are fewer component render.

```
Select::make('product_id')
   ...
   ->searchDebounce(1200)
```

*****Observation: i didn't included the `supplier_id` in `getSearchResultsUsing`

Comment: Thanks so much for your extensive reply. I also came to the conclusion that this is the way it should work. Would you by any change know it it is possible to access other form data in order to get the supplierId?